# How to delete a document from the firestore cloud and the corresponding item in recyclerview?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I use the next code to delete displayed documents in recyclerView from  cloud firestore by click on the recyclerView item.
The result is when I click on the item, document is deleted only from firestore.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
            String medicamentId = documentSnapshot.getId();

            collref.document(medicamentId).delete()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // Introduce a slight delay before notifying item removal
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                            }, 100); 
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {});
        }
    }
});
```

How deleted the item from both firestore and from recyclerView?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());` inside your `OnFailureListener`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, here are some useful resources ([1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) & [2](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166)) that might help.

Comment: Thanks @Alex mom for your reply.
firstly I have no idea about kotlin.
I think there is no error because the document is deleted from the firestore cloud and the problem is that the corresponding item is not deleted from recyclerview. NOTE I am using an instance of FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. thank you for your help.

Comment: The FirebaseUI `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` should automatically update when the item is deleted from the database, so you shouldn't need the `addOnSuccessListener`. If removing that does not solve the problem, show us how you initialize the adapter, and what debugging output you get.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen. Can you help me how to initialise the adapter.

Comment: If removing the success listener does not solve the problem, show us how you initialize the adapter, and what debugging output you get.